# Finitely generated, non abelian, infinite group

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, infinite-groups

I was making a diagram of different types of groups; finite /infinite, cyclic / non-cyclic, finitely generated / inifinitely generated, but realized that I didn't have any examples og infinite groups, that are both finitely generated and non -abelian. Does anyone have any examples? :)

I was thinking about creating an example based on matrices and matrix multiplication, but I didn't get very far. I know that since I am looking for a finitely generated group, It must be countable.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't it ?

Comment: @ZAF $\mathbb Z$ is abelian.

Comment: The question body and title disagree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The group $\langle a, b\rangle$ is

1. finitely generated: obviously, it is generated by $\{a, b\}$,
2. non-abelian: the elements $ab$ and $ba$ are two distinct elements,
3. infinite: The mapping $\mathbb N\to \langle a, b\rangle$ that maps $n$ to $a^n$ is injective.

Comment: Thanx alot! Guess I couldn't see the forest for the trees...      May I also ask if the group <a,b> of "ordered sequences of powers of the elements a and b" has any other name than just "the group generated by the non - commutative elements a and b"?

Comment: @AfterMath free group of rank 2

Comment: @AfterMath It's the free grop of $\{a,b\}$, or the free group of rank $2$ (since, up to isomorphism, all free groups over a set of the same cardinality are equal)

Answer (score 1):

Try $G=\mathbb Z \times S_3$.

Comment: Thanks! Good example :)

Answer (score 0):

For the curious, John Meier's *Groups, Graphs and Trees* as well as *Office Hours With A Geometric Group Theorist* edited by Matt Clay and Dan Margalit make great introductions to the world of infinite, finitely-generated groups!